# python try/except in loop

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Im using python 3 and i have this loop, which iterate on this list -

```
self.settings["db"]["host"] = ["db-0", "db-1"]
```

My problem is that it seems to send in `return self.conn` the first option all the time, 
db-0 instead of trying with db-1

I have 2 db container servers, and when i stop one of them - for example db-0 it should try `psycopg2.connect` with db-1

```
  def db_conn(self):
        try:
            for server in self.settings["db"]["host"]:
                self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=server,
                user=self.settings["db"]["user"],
                password=self.settings["db"]["password"],
                database=self.settings["db"]["database"],
                connect_timeout=5,
                )
                return self.conn
        except Exception:
            pass
```

if loop has not succeeded i dont want it to `return self.conn`, only if the try worked.

I also tried :

```
  def db_conn(self):
        try:
            for server in self.settings["db"]["host"]:
                self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=server,
                user=self.settings["db"]["user"],
                password=self.settings["db"]["password"],
                database=self.settings["db"]["database"],
                connect_timeout=5,
                )
        except Exception:
            pass
       return self.conn
```

Comment: Maybe put the try/except inside the loop?

Comment: What do you actually want to return? If your loop continues, you'll overwrite `self.conn` each time through the loop. Do you want to collect connection objects and return all of them?

Comment: @snakecharmerb i tried it also.. doesnt work

Comment: @chepner if a container in list is down psycopg2 connection should fail so the loop should stop when connection succeeded - and return the correct `self.conn` string with working `server`

Comment: Walk me through this. Suppose there are two elements of `self.settings["db"]["host"]`. If both servers can be connected to, do you want to return two connections? If the first server can be connected to, do you want to try the second at all? If none can be connected to, what exactly do you want returned? `None`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have 2 replication server so not in all times both of them will be up, so i wanted the code to try to connect and the server that works will be the connection at `self.conn` ,  if all servers are down then yes it will return None. I have already posted an answer, what i was missing was the `continue` in the `except:`

Answer (score 1):

You are looping within a `try`.
Do it the other way around,
push the `try` down within the loop.

The [DbC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) contract the current code is attempting to offer
is to return a valid connection.
Let's make that more explicit, by writing a very simple helper.
We will spell out its contract in a docstring.

```
def first_true(iterable, default=False, pred=None):
    # from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
    return next(filter(pred, iterable), default)


def get_conn_or_none(self, server):
    """Returns DB connection to server, or None if that's not possible."""
    try:
        return psycopg2.connect(
            host=server,
            user=self.settings["db"]["user"],
            password=self.settings["db"]["password"],
            database=self.settings["db"]["database"],
            connect_timeout=5,
        )
    except Exception:
        return None
```

Now `db_conn` is simply:

```
def db_conn(self):
    return first_true(map(self.get_conn_or_none, self.settings["db"]["host"]))
```

That uses the same logic as in your question.
You may want to have `db_conn` additionally check whether
all connection attempts failed, and `raise` fatal error in that case.

BTW, it's very odd that you're apparently storing a list of server hostnames
in self.settings["db"]["host"], given that an individual user / pw / db is
stored in the other fields.
Consider renaming that list to `self.servers`.

Comment: i get NameError: name 'get_conn_or_none' is not defined

Comment: `db_conn` can't find `self.get_conn_or_none`? And they're both defined in the same class?

Comment: It only returns "true" the db_conn , how an i supposed to connect to "true" ? i need more explanation on this code.

Comment: Argghh! Yeah, sorry, that's the trouble with OP code that the answerer cannot run himself. In fairness, for this question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be very hard to adhere to, since we'd need multiple DBs to connect to. Anyway I fixed the bug by replacing `any()` with `first_true()`. Sorry, I was translating from the Common Lisp `(or x1 x2 x3)`, and forgot that python `any()` applies `bool()` to its result. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node75.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have solved the problem in my code and have posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the connection status before returning it:

```
  def db_conn(self):
        try:
            for server in self.settings["db"]["host"]:
                self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=server,
                user=self.settings["db"]["user"],
                password=self.settings["db"]["password"],
                database=self.settings["db"]["database"],
                connect_timeout=5,
                )
                **if self.conn.isOk()**
                    return self.conn
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: if i know a way to check if the connection is ok i would. the try should do it as if the connection with one fails it should go on

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
def db_conn(self):
    for server in self.settings["db"]["host"]:
        try:
            self.print_info("TRYING", server)
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=server,
                user=self.settings["db"]["user"],
                password=self.settings["db"]["password"],
                database=self.settings["db"]["database"],
            )
        except:
            self.print_info("SERVER DOWN", server)
            continue
    return self.conn
```

continue will continue the rest of the code if i get exception ( failed connection)
then it goes back to for loop with the second item in list.